# Accessing additional paragraph-style properties with python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to parse a Word document using python-docx, but have trouble getting the correct styles of paragraphs. I have uploaded a simplified version of the file to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzaawfcme2jg0hh/test.docx?dl=0).
The document's 'Normal' style uses 'Garamont' font, but this is changed so that everywhere I click in the file, the font is 'Calibri (Body)'.

When I use the 'Style inspector' in Word on the *first line*, it shows: "Paragraph formatting" is `Normal` + `Plus: Centered, Left:  0 cm, Before:  0 pt`, and "Text level formatting" is `Default Paragraph Font` + `Plus: +Body (Calibri), 14 pt, Bold, Underline`.

When I do the same on a non-bold text in the *table*, I get: "Paragraph formatting" is `Normal` + `Plus: +Body (Calibri), Before:  0 pt`, and "Text level formatting" is `Default Paragraph Font` + `Plus: <none>`.

That is, the font is changed on different levels inside and outside of the table. In both case, however, I do not know how to get this info using python-docx:

```py
import docx
doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
par = doc.paragraphs[0]
#par = doc.tables[0].cell(0,1).paragraphs[0]
print(f"'{par.style.name}'")
print(f"'{par.style.font.name}'")
print(f"'{par.runs[0].font.name}'")
print(f"'{par.runs[0].style.name}'")
print(f"'{par.runs[0].style.font.name}'")

c = doc.tables[0].cell(1,0)
for par in c.paragraphs:
    print(f"{len(par.runs)}", end=' ')
c.paragraphs[0].add_run('Very short summary')
doc.save('test_ed.docx')
```

returns

```
'Normal'
'Garamond'
'None'
'Default Paragraph Font'
'None'
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

In other words, I do not see any sign that the document actually uses the Calibri font.
It returns exactly the same if I use the second `par` definition (from the table).

Moreover, looking at the resulting [test_ed.docx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rku5f03n5wd9r7q/test_ed.docx?dl=0), the added line is using 'Garamont', even if Word shows the other empty paragraphs as using 'Calibri (Body)'.

So, my question is how to detect the actual format of the text and how to copy it to new paragraphs?

Comment: Can you add demo code (complete and runnable, but stripped-down) that reads the paragraph style? It will make it a lot easier for somebody to help you -- and will make the question more useful to future readers. The Word file we can provide ourselves, I suppose :-)

Comment: @alexis I have now rewritten the question and also uploaded the file to Dropbox